# Software Updater is only showing the description for my application

Tags: update-manager

A program I've packaged isn't showing the name of my application, but only the description.

I've tried downloading a few packages from the Ubuntu repositories to see what they might be doing differently, but I haven't been able to find anything that's getting me anywhere.

Anything I can try? Here's the `control` file for the package if it helps:

```
Package: makedeb-alpha
Description: Create Debian archives from PKGBUILDs (alpha release)
Source: makedeb.sh
Version: 2.7.1-1
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Hunter Wittenborn <hunter@hunterwittenborn.com>, 
Depends: makepkg, dpkg-dev, binutils, file
Suggests: makedeb-db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like applications default back to their description in their `control` file if they don't have a `.desktop` file. I haven't tested it yet, but it looks like what's appearing to happen in general.